# add column with string length of another column and cumsum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-3.7

Given the following `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["kuku", "pu", "d", "fgf"]})
```

I want to calculate the length of each string and add a cumsum column.

I am trying to do this with `df.str.len("col1")` but it throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.len()`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["kuku", "pu", "d", "fgf"]})
df["New"] = df["col1"].str.len()
print(df)
print(df["New"].cumsum())   #cumulative sum
```

**Output:**

```
   col1  New
0  kuku    4
1    pu    2
2     d    1
3   fgf    3

0     4
1     6
2     7
3    10
Name: New, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can I chain them all to one line code? Like I do it in R?

Comment: Sure `df["New"] = df["col1"].str.len().cumsum()`

Answer (score 3):

The dataframe initialization code is wrong. Try this.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["kuku", "pu", "d", "fgf"]})
>>> df
   col1
0  kuku
1    pu
2     d
3   fgf
```

Alternatively, you can use `map` as well.

```py
>>> df.col1.map(lambda x: len(x))
0    4
1    2
2    1
3    3
```

To calculate length.

```py
>>> df['len'] = df.col1.str.len()
>>> df
   col1  len
0  kuku    4
1    pu    2
2     d    1
3   fgf    3
```

Answer (score 3):

Or 
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "col1" : ["kuku", "pu", "d", "fgf"]})
df['new'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Your **col1** argument is an unknown argument to pd.DataFrame()...
>
> Use **data** as the argument name instead... Then add your new column with the length

```
    data = {'col1': ["kuku", "pu", "d", "fgf"]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
    df["col1 lenghts"] = df["col1"].str.len()
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative I think solved my issue:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ['dilly macaroni recipe salad', 'gazpacho', 'bake crunchy onion potato', 'cool creamy easy pie watermelon', 'beef easy skillet tropical', 'chicken grilled tea thigh', 'cake dump rhubarb strawberry', 'parfaits yogurt', 'bread nut zucchini', 'la salad salmon']})

df["title_len"] = df[1].str.len()

df["cum_len"] = df["title_len"].cumsum()
```